# Ejabberd - Send & Receive messages via Bot

Tags: python, xmpp, ejabberd, sleekxmpp

I've written a bot `B` which receives messages from client `C1` and forwards it to client `C2`, ie 2 people can connect via the gateway `Bot`.

I'm using [Sleekxmpp](https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/), a python client XMPP library for the above purpose.

```
import logging

from sleekxmpp import ClientXMPP
from sleekxmpp.exceptions import IqError, IqTimeout

class EchoBot(ClientXMPP):

    def __init__(self, jid, password):
        ClientXMPP.__init__(self, jid, password)

        self.add_event_handler("session_start", self.session_start)
        self.add_event_handler("message", self.message)

    def session_start(self, event):
        self.send_presence()

    def message(self, msg):
        if msg['type'] in ('chat'):
            # receive message from the Client1
            from, to = message['from'], message['to']
            message = message['body']
            # send message to Client2. 
            self.send_message(mto=recipient,
                              mbody=message,
                              mtype='chat')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xmpp = EchoBot('bot@example.com', 'password')
    xmpp.connect()
    xmpp.process(block=True)
```

Now the problem that Client C2 receives the message by the BOT. It should rather receive it from Client C1. For that to happen, I need password of C1 to authorize C1, which I dont have it in the message body neither it is secure to send password in the body.

What is the best approach to create a gateway BOT?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can set a bot as a gateway for C1 to C2 by setting mfrom = C1 in send_message() method